# For loop using pexpect and a large list of addresses to do stuff with

Tags: python, for-loop, pexpect

I'm working with pexpect. Goal is to connect sequentially to a list of addresses in a text file, do stuff once connected, log out and move on to the next address.

I've got the basic functionality working just fine. It's the pesky errors. If the client doesn't respond, it just breaks. I've used 'try' but if there is an exception then it breaks the for loop and won't continue with the next address.

What is the best way to attempt each, do stuff, and if it breaks... make a note in a log file then move on to the next until we reach the end of the list. Here is my current:

```
i = open('addresses.txt')
addresses = i.readlines()
i.close()

for address in addresses:
  c = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s@%s' % (user, address))
  c.logfile = sys.stdout
  c.timeout = 5
  c.expect('something')
  c.sendline('do something')
   etc etc.
```

Comment: How did you use `try` in this? Please update the question with that

Comment: Put try inside of the loop and exception won't break it.

Comment: To log messages in a file have a look at the [Logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect specific and expected errors

```
errors = []
for address in addresses:
    try:
       c = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s@%s' % (user, address))
       c.logfile = sys.stdout
       c.timeout = 5
       c.expect('something')
       c.sendline('do something')
   except Exception as e:   # replace with the type of exception you expect
       errors.append(dict(address=address, exception=e))
```

This shouldn't break the `for` loop, and when done you can read the errors,

```
if errors:
    # report them, do something etc
    # the errors are informative, with address and exception objects in the dict
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. The examples I was working off of didn't complete the picture. Appreciated!